# VAE in Keras: how to define the end-to-end model?

Tags: python, keras, autoencoder

I am learning the [tutorial](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/fchollet/deep-learning-with-python-notebooks/blob/master/8.4-generating-images-with-vaes.ipynb) here. My Model part is:

```
input_img = keras.Input(shape=img_shape)

x = layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3),
                  padding='same', activation='relu')(input_img)

...
x = layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3),
                  padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
shape_before_flattening = K.int_shape(x)

x = layers.Flatten()(x)
x = layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(x)

z_mean = layers.Dense(latent_dim)(x)
z_log_var = layers.Dense(latent_dim)(x)

def sampling(args):
    ...

z = layers.Lambda(sampling)([z_mean, z_log_var])

decoder_input = layers.Input(K.int_shape(z)[1:])

x = layers.Dense(np.prod(shape_before_flattening[1:]),
                 activation='relu')(decoder_input)

x = layers.Reshape(shape_before_flattening[1:])(x)

x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, 3,
                           padding='same', activation='relu',
                           strides=(2, 2))(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(1, 3,
                  padding='same', activation='sigmoid')(x)

# This is our decoder model from letent space to reconstructed images
decoder = Model(decoder_input, x)

# We then apply it to `z` to recover the decoded `z`.
z_decoded = decoder(z)

def vae_loss(self, x, z_decoded):
    ...


# Fit the end-to-end model
vae = Model(input_img, z_decoded) # vae = Model(input_img, x)
vae.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss=vae_loss)
vae.summary()
```

My question is: the end-to-end is `vae = Model(input_img, z_decoded)` or `vae = Model(input_img, x)`. Should we compute loss on `input_img` and `z_decoded` OR between `input_img` and `x`? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

x is changing throughout the model, where `x = layers.Conv2D(1, 3,padding='same', activation='sigmoid')(x)` you set `x` to be the last layer of your decoder model. 
When doing `z_decoded = decoder(z)` you chain your decoder straight after the encoder, `z_decoded` is actually the output layer of your decoder, thus, the same `x` as earlier. Also, you create the link between the actual input and the output.

Computing the loss would yield the same results on both (as they both represent the same layer). 
In short - Both `vae = Model(input_img, z_decoded)` and `vae = Model(input_img, x)` are the end to end model, i would suggest using the z_decoded version, for readability.